# How to bind to data-content?

Tags: angular

I am trying use this code from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" 
data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" 
data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
   Click to toggle popover
</button>
```

However I am not able to bind to the attribute "data-content", it gives me the below error.

> Can't bind to 'content' since it isn't a known property of 'span'

This is my angular code

```
<span data-toggle="popover" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg" [data-content]="getTooltipMsg('lastName')"></span>
```

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: There is no binding for `data-content` in the code you posted. Is this actually the code you are using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Updated my question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Angular by default uses property binding, but there is no `data-content` property on the `span` element and there also doesn't seem to be an Angular component or directive with a `data-content` input on this element.

Therefore you need to use attribute-binding:

```
<span data-toggle="popover" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg" [attr.data-content]="getTooltipMsg('lastName')"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a dedicated library that provides Angular + Bootstrap integration - with such libraries opening a popover becomes as simple as:

```
<span [ngbPopover]="getTooltipMsg('lastName')" popoverTitle="Some title" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg" ></span>
```

Here is a live example using the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover) library: http://plnkr.co/edit/gTSxuZjx2ovkBAX0GWYQ?p=preview

Dedicated libraries like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover) not only provide APIs that feel natural in the Angular ecosystem but also allow you to drop dependency on jQuery.